# TypeError: AWS.SecretsManager is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs

I am trying to test the following code snippet

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
export const fetchSSMCertKey = async (certKeyArn: string): Promise<string> => {
    const secretsmanager: AWS.SecretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager();
    const data = await secretsmanager.getSecretValue({ SecretId: certKeyArn }).promise();
    if (!data.SecretString) {
        throw new Error();
    } else {
        return data.SecretString;
    }
};
```

with this jest test code

```
import * as types from '../../../types';
import type { SecretsManager } from 'aws-sdk';
jest.mock('aws-sdk');
describe('fetchSSMCertKey', () => {
    it('returns a value of secret', async () => {
        const secretValue = '---cert---key---value---';
        const mockSecretsManager = ({} as unknown) as SecretsManager;
        const mockPromise = Promise.resolve({ SecretString: secretValue });
        const mockPromiseFunc = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockPromise);
        mockSecretsManager.getSecretValue = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ promise: mockPromiseFunc });
        expect(await types.fetchSSMCertKey('find-me')).toEqual(secretValue);
    });
});
```

but I keep getting the error, running the code:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: AWS.SecretsManager is not a constructor
```

what is missing in my mock-preparation. Is there a way to init the SecretManager differently?

Comment: Does this error occur when you don't run the mocks? Maybe you are not providing a mock for the constructor?

Comment: yes the same error seems to occur when I disable the mocks.

Comment: Why do you say "seems" to occur?

Answer (score 0):

`aws-sdk` uses CommonJS module system and therefore you cannot use * import (i.e. `import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';`). Instead you should do:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const secretsmanager = new AWS.SecretsManager();
```